# RxJs, not display in dom, but console works

Tags: rxjs, observable, reactive-programming, observer-pattern, reactive

Why do the outputs only display in one of element
(#skip-result or #distinct-result) not both of them ?

but if i try outputting the result from those two observable
below to console it works

you can check code [here](https://jsbin.com/xirutax/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
var input$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input,'input')


var x$ = input$
  .debounce(1000)



// skip two character in string, from input value
// then, display it in #skip-result
x$
  .map(v=> v.target.value)
  .filter(v=> v.length > 2)
  .flatMap(v=> 
           Rx
             .Observable
             .from(v)
             .skip(2)
             .reduce((x,y)=> x + y)
  )
  .subscribe(s=>{
    $('#skip-result').text('Skip Value is ' + s)
  })



// search distinct in string, from input value
// then, display it in #distinct-result
x$
  .map(e=> e.target.value)
  .filter(e=> e.length > 0)
  .flatMap(v=> 
           Rx
             .Observable
             .from(v)
             .distinct()
             .reduce((x,y)=> x + y)
  )
  .subscribe(x=>{
    $('#distinct-result').text('Distinct value is ' +x)
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JSBin you've referenced, you haven't imported jQuery, but you appear to be using the jQuery selector to set the contents of both the `#skip-result` and `#distinct-result` DOM elements. This will throw an error.

If instead you changed them to set the `innerHTML` property, which one subscription already looks to be doing, you should get your expected behaviour.

```
.subscribe(s => {
  skipResult.innerHTML = 'Skip Value is ' + s
})
```

#### EDIT

After a second look, your markup isn't being closed properly. Specifically, `#skip-result` is being made a child of `#distinct-result`.

Comment: Had another look and I only just noticed your markup isn't being closed properly (see my edit). [Here's a working fork of your JSBin.](https://jsbin.com/huhowenowu/2/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: that's work, thanks i forgot close the `<div>` tag before